VS code intellisense does not work for imports due to problem with TS Server. How can i get it automatic again?
I have no idea why but a few days ago, intellisense in javascript for imports just stopped working.
After doing some research, suffering and reading the docs, VS code uses a typescript server which automatically installs npm types packages to a sort of global folder where it then becomes available to all projects. The process is called Automatic Type Acquisition and it happens when you complete an import statement.
For anyone interested, the folder it installs packages at is:
/usr/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Typescript/<version>. Any typescript types packages installed there (@types/package) will shou up on intellisense for imported modules.
However, no amount of reading the tsserver.log files gives an idea of how to solve the issue. To be clear, there are errors in the tsserver.log. (after i installed types registry)
[18:52:32.163] Response has been sent.
[18:52:32.163] #1 with cwd: C:/Users/<usr>/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/5.6 arguments: ["@types/lodash@ts5.6"]
[18:52:32.164] Exec: npm install --ignore-scripts @types/lodash@ts5.6 --save-dev --user-agent="typesInstaller/5.6.2"
[18:52:32.167]     Failed. stdout:
    stderr:
[18:52:32.168] npm install #1 took: 4 ms
[18:52:32.169] install request failed, marking packages as missing to prevent repeated requests: ["lodash"]
[18:52:32.169] Sending response:

It runs an npm command which fails without any clear error message. Also when i manually run that npm install to the same exact target address above it installs fine. For whatever reason, TS server is blocked from doing any installs using npm and i have no idea why or how to fix it. Especially when this was not an issue before.
Here is a list of steps i have taken:

ensuring node and npm are updated.
making sure the registry is the correct address
force clearing the npm cache
ensuring node and npm directories are correct in VS code (they arent an issue in the TS server)
changing file permissions / read only for the relevant folders
restarting machine, server and computer multiple times.
im not under any proxy and i am in an admin account.
every kind of jsconfig.json entry listed online
every meaningful combination of typescript tsserver and intellisense setting.

There was no effect except for small changes to the logs that didnt affect the main errors.
Right now i am content to manually install the global types as needed (treating Automatic Type Acquisition as down) especially as i only use a few regularly, but i would love to get back full functionality.
